# Assign two different UITapGestureRecognizer for a custom control using swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

using swift, I'm trying to create a dynamic and generic control to reuse it, basically, the control should have a general behavior inside.

To be more specific, I have a `UIScrollView` and it's filled using `UIViews`, when you click over an `UIView`, the background should change.
That is working correctly.

But, for the implementation, my class of the generic control, accepts a `Selector` as parameter.

Both works separately, but together are not working.

The specific part of codes are:

**Generic class**

```
let clickAgendaEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.agendaClicked (_:)))
cellSubView.addGestureRecognizer(clickAgendaEvent)
cell.addSubview(cellSubView)

let itemClickedEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: viewController.self, action: self.agendaItemClicked!  )
cell.addGestureRecognizer(itemClickedEvent)
```

And a `ViewController` with an implementation like this:

```
@objc func eventDailyAgenda(sender:UIView!){
        print("Item clicked!")
    }
```

As you can see, the second event, is not inside of the generic class, the second event is a separated implementation if the `ViewController`.
But, the generic class, would be implemented for other `UIViewController`.

Someone have an idea about how can handle it?

Comment: I think you have to implement GestureDelegate and return yes for gesture working simultaneosly `extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}`

Comment: I added it, but still not firing both

Comment: You are adding one gesture to one view and the another to another view I think that the frontmost view should pass the event to the background view

Comment: Or add both gestures to the frontMost view and only the second gesture to background view, I don't know If you understand what I saying

Comment: Yes, I tried, but both are added at the same `IUView` component, and the first one is fired but not the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to do it, is implementing `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.
But for my specific case didn't work, because, I have different classes implementing the behavior.

But, I found a way to do it.
And is implementing `NSObject` (if you are in a `UIViewController` you don't have to implement it.

For my case I have my class:

```
class MyClass:NSObject {

    func createAll(){
        let clickAgendaEvent = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.agendaClicked (_:)))
        cellSubView.addGestureRecognizer(clickAgendaEvent)
        cellSubView.tag = index
        cell.addSubview(cellSubView)
    }

        @objc func agendaClicked(_ sender:AnyObject) {
            baseView.setTransparentToSubViews()
            print("Here")

            let tap = sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer
            tap.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor().hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#e0e0e0")

            if let v = tap.view {
                // use button
                print("The tag is \(v.tag)")
            }


            if let c: NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString(viewController.className) as? NSObject.Type{
                let c_tmp = c.init()
                    c_tmp.perform(Selector(("test")))
                        c.perform(Selector(("static_test")))
        }
    }

}
```

Add in your `ViewController`

```
@objc public func test(){
        print("This is Test!!!")
    }
    @objc public class func static_test(){
        print("This is Static Test")
    }
```

And this extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder)
    }
}
```

Now, you can execute all the methods you want.

For this case, once the user touch an element, the next event is fired from the touch, and not is necessary to add a new delegate.

Maybe is not the better way, but is totally functional.

Answer (score 2):

Look into `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to handle both gestures simultaneously.  Check out the callback `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` .  Return true to have both handled simultaneously.

Comment: I just added the function `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }` and implemented `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but, is still now calling to both.

Comment: For my specific case, should I create a pan gesture to assign it?